# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to run a file?

Tags: windows

I have a python script that I want to run when I do a specific key press.

What I have tried is making a shortcut of the script and then assigning a shortcut key to that shortcut but this only works if I am in the same directory as the shortcut.

AutoHotkey is an option but I am looking for a simpler way.

Comment: You need to specify full paths and a proper command line. EG For VBScript `"c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe" "C:\My Folder\MyScript.vbs"`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I have tried is making a shortcut of the script and then assigning a shortcut key to that shortcut. But this only works if I am in the same directory as the shortcut.

Placing the shortcut on your desktop should alleviate this problem under most circumstances (i.e. the shortcut combination for that script should generally be available under normal use).

---

*Theoretically, some programs that capture the full window/keyboard input might still potentially interfere with this.*

---